# VBA Print Array to Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I understand there are many similar questions but none of the ones I looked at solved my issue.
I'm completely new to VBA and I don't understand how its data structures work.

I'm getting a JSON string from a web API and I'm trying to print a specific field into the spreadsheet.
The JSON has the following format:

```
{
   "responses":[
      {
         "responseId":"someId",
         "values":{
            ...,
            "QID2":1
         }
      },
      {
         "responseId":"someOtherId",
         "values":{
            ...,
            "QID2":2
         }
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

The fields I'm interested in are the "QID2"s, which always have a value in range [1,3].
Here's my code to parse and print this JSON:

```
 'Load response into sheet
    Dim Parsed As Dictionary: Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(oHttp.responseText)
    Dim Responses As Variant
    ReDim Responses(Parsed("responses").Count)

    Dim Response As Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0
    For Each Response In Parsed("responses")
        Responses(i) = Response("values")("QID2")
    Next Response

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Parsed("responses").Count, 1)) = Responses
```

I've checked using Debug.Print that `Responses` contains varied values (a combination of 1's, 2's and 3's). But the output of this code only prints a column of 1's on the sheet.
How can I properly print the array `Responses` to a sheet?

EDIT: On closer inspection, my loop seems weird in that it doesn't increment `i` (I copied this syntax from somwhere). Is this correct?

Comment: `i = i + 1` inside the Loop... I suppose that `Parsed("responses").Count > 1`.

Comment: You have initialized a horizontal array (per definition). You'll have to transpose your array to fill your vertical range > `Application.Transpose(Responses)`. If you don't transpose your array, it will fill all cells with the first element from your array.

Comment: I had tried i = i + 1 and Application.Transpose before but not both together. It now works using both.

Comment: If answer is satisfactory, can you mark as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to see how to transpose an array manually into a temp array, and output as a function.

```
    Function TransposeDim(v As Variant) As Variant
    ' Custom Function to Transpose a 0-based array (v)

    Dim x As Long, y As Long, Xupper As Long, Yupper As Long
    Dim tempArray As Variant

    Xupper = UBound(v, 2)
    Yupper = UBound(v, 1)

    ReDim tempArray(Xupper, Yupper)
    For x = 0 To Xupper
        For y = 0 To Yupper
            tempArray(x, y) = v(y, x)
        Next y
    Next x

    TransposeDim = tempArray

End Function
```

Comment: Why would you build your own `Application.Transpose` function? Out of curiosity =)

Comment: @JvdV `Application.Transpose` has a limit ~62,000.  This allows the transposition of any size array.

Comment: Hi JvdV. There's been cases over the years where I needed to pull specific things out of the array during the transpose. One the problems involved unicode place holder characters which needed to be removed from the array before printing the page. Id transpose the array into 2 different temp arrays, then run the unicode removal on the one before merging back. It was to wrap my single-threaded brain around the multi-threaded problem XD...and yes for ADODB transpose... like scott said ^ limit.